# Remove LESS // comments on compile

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to configure LESS to remove "// comments" when it compiles via JS?

I want to remove them from the outputted less file.

Comment: @Ennui Sorry, I did not know about `//` being valid LESS comments. Although I think this is dangerous. @RaphaelDDL I do know what LESS is. Calm down.

Comment: @kleinfreund no problem, turns out I was wrong too as `//` are supposed to be "silent" comments (not present in compiled code).  Although if that's true I don't know why this question exists in the first place.  I'm used to SASS which just converts them to normal comments.

Comment: @Ennui On SCSS, `//` don't turn to normal CSS comments. Dunno about old SASS.. || @kleinfreund Why would // be dangerous? Because they are JS comment as well? But then, /* */ is also a JS comment, so would it be dangerous too :P?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Less' single-line comments `//` are supposed to be silent, as per documentation states:

> Single-line comments are also valid in LESS, but they are ‘silent’, they don’t show up in the compiled CSS output:

```
// Hi, I'm a silent comment, I won't show up in your CSS
.class { color: white }
```

See at LESS' website: http://lesscss.org/#-comments

`-x` flag works on command line to output minified CSS (which will strip CSS comments), but in any way, double slash shouldn't appear on css. See http://lesscss.org/#usage at 'Command-line usage' topic.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding JS usage without the CLI tool, the [docs say](http://lesscss.org/#using-less-configuration):

> You may pass some options to the compiler:

Unfortunately, those options aren't specified anywhere. You have to know where to look in the code, which is here: https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/0c2c1b2ba3036c62be5fc4e6232d3c0493559764/lib/less/env.js

The various options are (at time of this writing, from the above-linked blob):

```
var parseCopyProperties = [
    'paths',            // option - unmodified - paths to search for imports on
    'optimization',     // option - optimization level (for the chunker)
    'files',            // list of files that have been imported, used for import-once
    'contents',         // map - filename to contents of all the files
    'contentsIgnoredChars', // map - filename to lines at the begining of each file to ignore
    'relativeUrls',     // option - whether to adjust URL's to be relative
    'rootpath',         // option - rootpath to append to URL's
    'strictImports',    // option -
    'insecure',         // option - whether to allow imports from insecure ssl hosts
    'dumpLineNumbers',  // option - whether to dump line numbers
    'compress',         // option - whether to compress
    'processImports',   // option - whether to process imports. if false then imports will not be imported
    'syncImport',       // option - whether to import synchronously
    'javascriptEnabled',// option - whether JavaScript is enabled. if undefined, defaults to true
    'mime',             // browser only - mime type for sheet import
    'useFileCache',     // browser only - whether to use the per file session cache
    'currentFileInfo'   // information about the current file - for error reporting and importing and making urls relative etc.
];
```

and:

```
var evalCopyProperties = [
    'silent',         // whether to swallow errors and warnings
    'verbose',        // whether to log more activity
    'compress',       // whether to compress
    'yuicompress',    // whether to compress with the outside tool yui compressor
    'ieCompat',       // whether to enforce IE compatibility (IE8 data-uri)
    'strictMath',     // whether math has to be within parenthesis
    'strictUnits',    // whether units need to evaluate correctly
    'cleancss',       // whether to compress with clean-css
    'sourceMap',      // whether to output a source map
    'importMultiple', // whether we are currently importing multiple copies
    'urlArgs'         // whether to add args into url tokens
];
```

They are also documented a bit by the various Grunt and Gulp plugins that use LESS via JS.

So, to answer your question, you can't really strip out `/**/` comments without using `compress`. Which does all other sorts of things too.

Answer (score 6):

**2015-July update:** when trying the `-x` option as the other answers suggested, I got this warning:

> The compress option has been deprecated. We recommend you use a dedicated css minifier, for instance see less-plugin-clean-css.

You can install [the plugin](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css) with

```
npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
```

Then run `lessc` with the `--clean-css` argument.

Comment: Well, whether `-x` is deprecated or not, the Q itself is nothing but the OP mistake because (any) Less compiler *never* outputs `//` comments regardless of any options.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `-x` option to your `lessc` compile command will minify the CSS, which should strip out comments.  In the event it doesn't you can get more control over the minification options by using the [YUI CSS compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/css.html) by adding the `--yui-compress` option to your compile command, which definitely strips out comments.

Like Raphael said in his answer `//` style comments should not be present in compiled CSS anyway so your question doesn't make a lot of sense in the first place.

All of this information is clearly stated on the [LESS homepage / documentation](http://lesscss.org/), so maybe you should just read that first.

Comment: While LESS is wonderful, LESS homepage/documentation is pretty bad.

Comment: There is only /very/ limited documentation on using the compiler from JavaScrtipt, so you have to know to look at https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/env.js for all the options. You tell me, do you see anywhere on the LESS homepage where it says the `-x` equivalent in JS? No. Which is probably why you didn't actually answer's OP's question, which was about JS.

Comment: This is pretty much it on the less homepage: http://lesscss.org/#using-less-configuration