# Less Variables : Compiling variables inside comments

Tags: css, less, comments

I want to convert variables on the time of compilation but those variables are inside comment section

`@text-font-level-3 : 25px;`
`@text-font-level-4 : 30px;`

`font-size : @text-font-level-4 /* rtl: @text-font-level-3 */;`

So I need the output is like.
`font-size : 30px /* rtl : 25px */;`

Please help me with this.. thanks in advance..

Comment: its does not compile as it commented css so., here similar Question. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906286/remove-less-comments-on-compile)

Comment: @Mr_vasu Yes but we have some thing in SCSS to compile the variables inside comments also, there will be a way for less also but I am still searching for it..